# construct new pandas data frame from existence one

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like the following snipping

[image]

the data is as the following: [codprg   SEX counts
6558    1.0 9
6558    2.0 9
8683    1.0 9
8683    2.0 9
10985   1.0 9
10985   2.0 9
11050   1.0 4
11050   2.0 7
13365   1.0 9
13365   2.0 9
16510   1.0 8
16510   2.0 9
]
I want to have the covert it to a new data frame also with three columns [codprg, 1,2] where 1 contains the corresponding count and column(2) contains the corresponding count to 2. Like the following snipping

[image]

per in mind that the codprg become unique in each line in the second data frame

Comment: Paste data as text, not as pictures

Comment: No, my situation is the reverse @jezrael

Comment: I couldn't do it, could you please do it for me ?! @jezrael

Comment: I will write a new form of a question, please don't mark it as asked before so the others can answer my question. because you mark the question as duplicated and it's not   @jezrael

Comment: If it is dupe, I mark it, else not. This question is clear dupe, what code you try?

Comment: Can you explain why it is not dupe? Because if not dupe, I have no problem reopen question.

Comment: I show a sample of data and asked if there is any possibility to rebuild this data in another format.  where is the dupe here @jezrael

Comment: Do you try `df.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='val0')` - here `df.pivot(index='codprg', columns='SEX', values='counts')` ?

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it now @jezrael